# Thermostat does not reach desired temp

Tags: thermostat, heating

The thermostat was placed 9 months ago and the boiler was serviced at the same time. Anyway, I had the bedrooms temp held at 70 starting this morning and the maximum it got at 5 pm was 68. I turned off the living room heaters to see how this works independently.
So either the boiler is slow or the thermostat has an issue but I can not tell. The windows are shut.
The living rooms thermostat works just fine. When it’s set at 70 within a few hours it reaches 70 or 71. The living room is much bigger than the bedroom.
I am not sure if I should call the boiler company first or the thermostat company? None do both.
Thanks much in advance

Comment: it might need to be calibrated

Comment: Is the "68" a reading on the thermostat or from a separate thermometer?

Comment: The 68 is on the thermostat that is set to be 70.

Comment: what kind of heating do you have ? is it floor heating

Comment: Then it isn't a calibration issue. Either the thermostat is having serious problems (unlikely for 9 months old, but *if it has a battery, replace it just in case*) or, more likely, I suspect the boiler just isn't quite up to the task. Set the thermostat for 65 and see if cycles properly (should stay on until 66, then off until 64 then back on again).

Comment: Check the **calibration** with another thermostat read out

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The boiler is big enough to heat another bigger room

Comment: Yes the boiler is working well for the zone that includes kitchen living room. The bedrooms are smaller and are in a different zone. The bedroom thermostat does ok for lower temperatures up to 68 but it does not not go above that and it’s slow.

Comment: So you have some kind of zone controller

Comment: Maybe you tell us the **full story*. What type of heating to you have? Forced air ? or floor heating ?  Multiple zone dampers (controllers), use separate thermostat to double check the temperature read

Comment: It is forced air. Multiple zones with separate thermostats

Comment: Zoned forced air with a boiler is an unusual setup. Nonetheless, if that's what you actually have, there may be a duct control that limits the airflow to the bedrooms.  That may be failing. Hard to say without knowing more about your system.

Comment: Forced air from a fan coil unit? You said there was a boiler. so either you meant furnace, not boiler, or the boiler needs a way to make hot air from hot water. In any case, you appear to have a balancing problem if one area heats easily and another area does not - how you address that problem depends drastically on what's actually doing the heating, so clearing up "boiler or furnace" would be step zero.

Comment: I stand corrected: definitely boiler system , radiant heat, multiple zones . Thank you

Comment: The thermostat this morning was set at 70 and by 2 pm when I returned home it had reached 70 degrees. I have not programmed it myself and yesterday was one degree warmer.

Comment: I think a wire might be loose behind the thermostat?!